Why does a lever throw objects higher when they are placed farther from the fulcrum, despite force being greater near the fulcrum?
I've been experimenting with a lever and fulcrum setup while playing with my little brother. We used a ball of mass say $m$, which falls from a height say $h$ onto the effort arm of the lever to apply a force. The load (object to be thrown) is placed at various distances from the fulcrum on the load arm.
One thing I noticed is that the farther the object is from the fulcrum, the higher it is thrown, whereas placing it closer to the fulcrum results in less height and no height at all when the object is placed directly above the fulcrum. This seems counterintuitive to what I know about static forces in levers, where a greater force is applied closer to the fulcrum on the effort arm.
Here’s what I’ve considered:

I initially applied the work-energy theorem, where I equated the work done by the falling ball (via the distance over which the force is applied at the load arm of lever, which I approximated as the height of a triangle) to the kinetic energy of the ball. This gave me an average force. By using conservation of torque, I calculated the force applied to the object on the load arm. But this approach suggested the force would be greater when the object is closer to the fulcrum, which contradicts the observation that the object reaches a greater height when placed farther from the fulcrum.

I thought about using the conservation of energy, but that approach didn’t seem appropriate either, as the potential energy of the falling ball wouldn’t fully transfer to the object. For instance, an object placed right above the fulcrum gains no height, regardless of its mass.


I'm unclear about my thoughts, from my current understanding, I think  while the angular velocity and angular acceleration of the lever are constant along its length, the linear velocity and acceleration vary depending on the distance from the fulcrum. So, even though the force applied by the lever is theoretically greater near the fulcrum, the linear velocity imparted to the object is higher when placed farther away, resulting in a greater throw height.
Could someone clarify this behavior? Why does the object achieve greater height when placed farther from the fulcrum, even though the force seems to be greater near the fulcrum in static scenarios?

Think about the VR. You will get your answer

Try conserving angular momentum. Ignore the flexing of the lever.

because then level applies greater torque $\boldsymbol {\tau }= \mathbf {r} \times \mathbf {F}$

The object is thrown higher when it is further from the fulcrum because the lever is moving more rapidly upwards there. Yes, the force that the lever is capable of applying is greater near the fulcrum, but that's irrelevant because you need to distinguish between the force that is capable of being applied and the force that is actually applied.
To appreciate the difference, consider two extreme examples. Imagine you throw a cricket ball or you hit one with the blade of a bulldozer crawling at an inch-per-second. The thrown ball will travel much further and faster than the ball that is hit by the bulldozer, notwithstanding the fact that the force the bulldozer can apply might be thousands of times greater than the force that can be applied by your arm.
The problem with simply applying equations such as f=ma is that you need to apply them realistically, taking into account what is actually happening. In the case of the ball being pushed by the bulldozer, the moment the blade touches the ball, the ball recoils somewhat, and once the speed of recoil matches the speed of the blade, there is no effective contact and the ball is no longer being accelerated.
The same applies in the case of the object on the lever. The lever will accelerate the object only while the two are in contact. Once the speed of the object exceeds the speed of the lever, they lose contact and the acceleration stops. So an object placed close to the fulcrum, where the lever is moving slowly, will stop accelerating at a lower speed than an object placed far from the fulcrum.

The 'force near the fulcrum' in a lever is NOT great.   The test object
placed near the fulcrum has nearly zero acceleration, thus sees
nearly zero applied force when the lever is moved.   $F = M \times a$
The force application at such an object isn't great unless you keep the
object stationary while applying force.   The dynamics of a
moving-ball input is not easily reconciled with a force-ratio
picture, because that moving-ball has momentum and a very
complex force-versus-time behavior as it accelerates while out of
lever contact and then slams into the lever (which rebounds...).

Instead of applying $F = ma$ If i apply $Fd = (1/2) mv²$ for effort arm as well (Work energy principal). Thats is giving me reasonable values same as expected from physical behaviours. For distance which is closer to fulcrum, will experience force for short distance (d = that height of triangle) thats $Fd = (1/2) mv²$ will give less value of velocity So is that fine?
